# Spring Boot Rest Api not displaying validation message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am developing a small REST API by using Spring Boot. I am using validation annotations in my entity class:

```
@NotEmpty(message="Please enter a first name")
private String firstName;
```

Here is my controller and service:

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService userService;

    @PostMapping("/customer")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Customer postUser (@RequestBody @Valid Customer customer){

      return userService.save(customer);

    } 
}
```

```
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public Customer save ( Customer customer){

        return repository.save(customer);
    }
}
```

Here is the response I get when I try to send a JSON with an empty firstName Value:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-08T08:40:08.660+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/MVCwebshop/customer"
}
```

As you can see, the "message" field is empty in the JSON I get. This is also happening when I try to use the default messages. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do Bean Validation with Hibernate Validation in Spring Boot app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229062/how-to-do-bean-validation-with-hibernate-validation-in-spring-boot-app)

Comment: What does the exception stack trace print say?

Comment: Also check for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248960/why-vaild-annotation-is-not-working-in-my-spring-mvc-application-i-searched-a) common mistake while using bean validation.

Answer (score 10):

In case of using Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE you have to set

```
server.error.include-message=always
```

in your application.properties (or yaml).

See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21132)

Comment: Hello, im getting the error count only after put this property (server.error.include-message=always) in my application.properties:

{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-25T17:25:49.475+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Validation failed for object='memberRequestDTO'. Error count: 1",
    "path": "/bookings/api/members/"
}

I want display the error message for that field, that would be:

"@Size(min = 3, max = 50, message = "The member surname must contain between 3 and 50 characters.")"

How can i make this?

Comment: Somehow not working for me in Spring Boot 3

Answer (score 4):

Along with `server.error.include-message=always` as mentioned above,
you can also add `server.error.include-binding-errors=always` to application.properties.
This will list all the binding errors, along with the specific message

Answer (score 0):

You can add the validation query :

```
@NotEmpty(message="Please enter a first name")
@Size(min= 1, max = 50, message="actor.firstName.size")
private String firstName;
```